# Scoping my first project

Tags: java, libgdx

So I'm writing my first game which is a RTS and one of my main ideas for it is multiplayer deception however I'm finding it hard to control the scope of my project. Yes im thinking pretty small but because a key element of the game is multiplayer I'm wondering if its a good idea for a first game I know APIs such as appwarp exist and allow easier multiplayer integration but is this realistic for a first game or is it a better idea to go single player?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTS's are probably one of the hardest game genres to make because of the huge amount of balancing that has to be done between different units, then on top of that multiplayer adds another layer of complexity...

for example look at GreyGoo an RTS made by a proper development studio, they had the experience to balance the game but because of networking trouble in the early release most of the players left quickly and never looked back.

I'm not saying that it is impossible to do as a first game it is just very unlikely to become anything playable. Your first game will probably be something that nobody will ever play (because you will most likely never release), it will be the project that teaches you the basics.

For a good place to start into looking what your first (few) game(s) will take the form off, look at Extra Credits "Making Your First Game" series ([starting here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z06QR-tz1_o)). Watch all 4 the episodes on it and by the end you will have a rough plan on what to do. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks I've watched quite a bit of extra credit already :D what would you recommend? I don't want to be bored out of my mind making a game that I don't really care about like my RTS idea wasn't exactly big its just whether the networking would be too much for a first game :) whats your opinion?

Comment: Well i would start with a one level platformer (yes a bit boring but doable), focus on code getting the player to move using the keyboard, jumping, landing on platforms, maybe something you can jump on to make it disappear and add score to a counter. Don't worry about menus or making it look good (unless you want to make art an assets too). Then just go from there, go 3D adjust your controls possibly make the mouse rotate the camera (first or 3rd person)... look at games that you play and see if you can implement a system or two from them once you've made a game or two, inventory systems etc.

Comment: Do you think making platformers would teach me any skills for strategy games though ? They seem very different in terms of construction

Comment: Well think of it this way, for your first game you will be figuring out how the engine works. What it likes how to properly code in it, import assets etc. Every engine is different so figuring out the basics is important for any game. If you don't want to do any of that you could just make a bunch of tech demos which you can then combine for your RTS later. possibly a small area where you can select a bunch of boxes and tell them were to go, like commanding units.